# Merge Excel Rows with duplicate

Tags: excel, duplicates, row

I have this table in Excel

[image] 
and I want to merge the row with the equal values of the 2 columns to obtain this table
[image]

I have no idea how to do: can you help me? I have read Excel tutorial but I have found only instruction about delete rows

Comment: I dont think you can use formulas to do this
you need to write some code in VBA.
Find a VBA book and start experimenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not want to jsut do it for you, since you did not even attempt to solve it. But i was too bored. 
Try this.

```
Sub mergeSmilar()

    'mydata starts from 1
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 2

    Do While (i <= Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)


        If (Range("A" & i) = Range("A" & i - 1)) And (Range("B" & i) = Range("B" & i - 1)) Then
            'row i should be merged to the i-1 row
            For j = 3 To 7 ' change 7 to number of columns you need to merge
                If (Trim(Cells(i - 1, j)) = "") Then
                    Cells(i - 1, j) = Cells(i, j)
                End If
            Next j
            Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
            i = i + 1
        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```